# WebRTC AEC not working on Android with USB Camera

Tags: android, webrtc, audio-processing, aec, echo-cancellation

We have a webrtc enabled service with 2 different endpoints; a web app and a native android app. The android app is installed on a android device with a USB Camera.

Using the web app on chrome/firefox, pc2pc audio quality is almost perfect. But we want to improve pc2android and android2android audio quality.

Chrome uses acoustic echo cancellation (AEC - conference) for high-end devices. But for Android it forces AECM -- a light-weight AEC for mobiles. We are not happy with the AECM performance. For our native app, we modify webrc source-code to use AEC instead. But the result is even worse. It acts like echo cancellation is totally disabled and we end up having so much echo and feedback!

According to [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=2580), AEC should only work with 8k and 16k sample rates and only in high-end devices. That should be OK. We are using PCMU codec having 8k sample rate and I think our Android device is powerful enough to overcome the additional computational complexity of AEC:

- Quad core ARM CPU @ 2Ghz
- 8 core Mali-450MP GPU @ 600Mhz
- DDR3 1GB RAM
- Android Kit Kat

If needed, I'm happy to share plots of our echo cancellation performance.

Is it not possible to use AEC for mobiles or are we missing something?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to adjust the latency for estimate the echo.